How to hide BibTeX keys from hyperref pdflinks
I am using hyperref to create a PDF that includes pdflinks for citations, sections etc.
Imagine the following MWE:
\documentclass{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}

In this document, we will cite a reference. The first citation is \cite{veryAkwardBibID} and the second is \cite{absolutelyNotMyCreditCardNumber}.

\section{Conclusion}

We cited two references. See \cite{veryAkwardBibID} again. For more, see section \ref{intro}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{veryAkwardBibID}
  Author One,
  \emph{Sample Title One}, 
  Journal of Testing, 
  1(2020), 1-10.

\bibitem{absolutelyNotMyCreditCardNumber}
  Author Two,
  \emph{Sample Title Two}, 
  Journal of Testing, 
  2(2021), 11-20.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}

Once the PDF is created, e.g. with pdfLaTeX, the pdflink for the introduction is called section.1 in the PDF metadata and does not keep its original label intro. You can check this e.g. by opening the PDF with FireFox and hovering your mouse over the pdflink (Adobe Reader, Edge, and Chrome do not show this like FireFox does). In the lower left corner of the screen, it will say .../example.pdf#section.1. This is exaclty want I want for sections. The same applies to figures and tables by the way.
However, for the citations, the pdflink will appear like .../example.pdf#cite.veryAkwardBibID, i.e. it keeps the original BibTeX key. I do not want this.
Question: How do you "hide" the original BibTeX keys from the created pdflinks (or rather from the PDF metadata entirely) similar to the labels originally given to sections?

Obviously, one solution would be to change the BibTeX keys manually in the first place to not include any information that should not appear. Of course, the key absolutelyNotMyCreditCardNumber in the MWE is just an exaggerated case to highlight the issue. A more real-life example would be that the BibTeX keys of the document are just very cryptic or are sounding unprofessional in some way and, thus, should be hidden from the public.
I am using numeric citation format. Thus, one preferred result would be to have .../example.pdf#cite.1 for reference [1] and so on. Alternatively, I would be fine with having some hashed version of the BibTeX key, e.g. by applying a SHA algorithm to the original BibTeX key.

another reason might be if your bibkeys include something like my-paper and you are submitting for blind review. (or even that your bibkeys use given names for people you know and family names for people you don't.)

in the end, I suspect there will be a need for a more general solution here which hashes all anchors and targets to prevent data leaking into the pdf. however, I have no idea if that is ever likely to happen. for this particular case you could redefine \@bibitem to take 2 arguments and then redefine \bibitem so it uses a counter for one of them and the cite key for the other. or so it passes on a hashed cite key and the cite key, for example. and then something similar for \cite{}. but I do not know what deleterious consequences this might have ....

do you know how the anchors appear if you use Biblatex? I assume you don't want to use a .bib for some reason?

In fact, I am using BibLaTeX (and memoir if that's relevant) with a .bib file. I just wanted to keep the MWE minimal. Your first comment on given/family names is a good real-life example.

With BibLaTeX and .bib file, the anchor looks like .../example.pdf#cite.0@bibtexkey (always zero).

hyperref does not "hide" the label name. When counters are involved (as for the section) the anchor names are created based on these anchors. The label only passes (through the aux-file) the information around, your label e.g. writes this into the aux-file:
\newlabel{intro}{{1}{2}{Introduction}{section.1}{}} 

and so it is easy for the reference to create a link to section.1.
With citations the situation is more complicated. With the classical system (so without biblatex) bibliography entries write a \bibcite into the aux with two argument. The first is in the key and the second contains (more or less) the text the citation should print. Depending on the bibliography style and package the second argument could take various forms and so is not suitable as a link anchor. Which means hyperref had to use the key.
That said, if you additionally load natbib it is rather trivial to apply some function to the key and to obfuscate it this way (the hash command is only an example, up-to-you to find a suitable function, that gives you the needed secrecy.). With biblatex something similar would be possible too.
\documentclass{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\hyper@natanchorstart#1{%
  \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{cite.\str_mdfive_hash:e{#1}}}%
}
\def\hyper@natlinkstart#1{%
  \Hy@backout{#1}%
  \hyper@linkstart{cite}{cite.\str_mdfive_hash:e{#1}}%
  \def\hyper@nat@current{#1}%
}
\def\hyper@natlinkbreak#1#2{%
  \hyper@linkend#1\hyper@linkstart{cite}{cite.\str_mdfive_hash:e{#2}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother  
\begin{document}
aaa\newpage
\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}

In this document, we will cite a reference. The first citation is \cite{veryAkwardBibID} and the second is \cite{absolutelyNotMyCreditCardNumber}.

\section{Conclusion}

We cited two references. See \cite{veryAkwardBibID} again. For more, see section \ref{intro}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{veryAkwardBibID}
  Author One,
  \emph{Sample Title One}, 
  Journal of Testing, 
  1(2020), 1-10.

\bibitem{absolutelyNotMyCreditCardNumber}
  Author Two,
  \emph{Sample Title Two}, 
  Journal of Testing, 
  2(2021), 11-20.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}

The anchor then looks for example like cite.2743D83EC111B077A119853A639515F9.

If possible, could you expand your answer to the BibLaTeX case, please? I am indeed using that and not natbib. If relevant, my document class of choice is memoir. I did not include BibLaTeX/memoir in my MWE to keep it minimal and because I did not suspect this information to be relevant since the question is rather about hyperref

ask a new question with a biblatex example.

Will be done. I accepeted this answer for now

The new question can be found here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/728425/hide-bib-keys-from-pdf-anchors-created-with-hyperref-explicitly-using-biblatex
