Hide bib keys from PDF anchors created with hyperref, explicitly using BibLaTeX
I am using the document class memoir and the packages biblatex and hyperref to create a PDF that includes pdflinks/anchors for citations, sections etc.
This is a direct follow-up to this question.
Imagine the following MWE, consisting of the TeX file and the bibliography file.
% This is the TeX file: example.tex
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\label{intro}
Let's cite a reference: \cite{absolutelyNotMyCreditCardNumber}.

\chapter{Conclusion}
The introduction was given in chapter \ref{intro}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}

The bibliography file:
% This is the bibliography file: references.bib

@article{absolutelyNotMyCreditCardNumber,
  author  = {Author One},
  title   = {Sample Title One},
  year    = {2020},
  journal = {Journal of Testing},
}

I am compiling with lualatex and biber from TeX Live 2019.
Observation: Once compiled, the anchor to the introduction will look like .../example.pdf#chapter.1. The anchor to the reference will look like .../example.pdf#cite.0@absolutelyNotMyCreditCardNumber. This can be inspected by opening the created PDF file in FireFox and hovering the mouse over the respective pdflink (Adobe Reader, Edge, Chrome will not show this, but those anchors will of course be stored somewhere in the PDF metadata).
Question: How do I "hide" the original key absolutelyNotMyCreditCardNumber given to the bibliography item such that it will not be stored in the PDF file? I am fine with the numbered format of the chapter anchor (which will look similar for figures or tables).
Preferred result: It is preferred that the bib keys currently shown in the anchors are anonymized by using a hash function, transforming the original keys to hashes which are not relatable to the original keys anymore. It is not desired to manually change the bib keys in the first place. The suggested automatic solution with hash functions is preferred.

The reasoning behind this question is that, when writing a document with references, you might use very cryptic, unprofessionally sounding, or otherwise inappropriate bib keys which you want to hide from the public. One real-life example: You are writing a scientific article which will be submitted for blind review. However, your bib keys are called my_paper_from_2019 and so on, which does not align with the requirements of a strict blind review.
This question gives the desired solution when using natbib instead of biblatex and the article class instead of memoir (I am not sure whether the choice of the document class makes a difference for the answer, so I included it in the MWE).

simply use the same definitions as with natbib. biblatex uses them if they are defined and it should work.

@UlrikeFischer Do you want to type up a quick answer here?
